# Is there an Open Source UML tool that can handle "association classes" and export java code?

Tags: java, open-source, uml

I am looking for an open source UML tool that can handle association classes. So far I have looked at several out there (ArgoUML, Fujaba, etc.) and unfortunately so far none of them support association classes. Also, the tool must have the ability to generate Java code from the diagram, including the ability to generate the proper code for the association class diagram. Thanks a lot for your input.

Cheers,
Luis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are on Windows check [StarUML](http://staruml.sourceforge.net/en/)  it supports association classes

Comment: StarUML does have association classes in its toolkit. But when you generate Java source code the association class is missing the proper attributes which connects the association class with the other two classes in the diagram. So the diagram looks correct, but the source code is not.

Comment: So far StarUML seems to have the closest match between the association class UML diagram and the resulting source code.

Answer (score 0):

The NetBeans [UML plugin](http://netbeans.org/features/uml/) represent association classes and of course generate source code ... and reverse ...

Comment: NetBeans 6.8 no longer supports UML :(

Comment: Ok. I found a way to add in the plugins that are no longer officially supported in Netbeans 6.8. However the code generation in Netbeans does not generate the source code for association classes. Back to square one.

Answer (score 0):

ArgoUML does support association classes (check again! :-) )

Answer (score 0):

ArgoUML supports both association classes and Java code generation.

What caused you to disqualify it as a solution?